Passing Airflow Variables to a constructor
I have a PythonOperator task that requires arguments to be passed to the constructor before the python callable is invoked.
PythonOperator(task_id='mytask',
               provide_context=True,
               python_callable=foo(var="{{ var.json.mydict }}").run,
               dag=dag)

I was previously loading the variable with Variable.get('mydict', deserialize_json=True), however that is not best practice and was causing a Broken DAG due to runtime.
However I have not had any luck trying to get anything involving the Jinja template to work. I have also tried:
PythonOperator(task_id='mytask',
               provide_context=True,
               op_kwargs={'var' : "{{ var.json.mydict }}" },
               python_callable=foo(**op_kwargs).run,
               dag=dag)

But this does not appear to work either. Please tell me what I am doing wrong!

You need to make sure that the template variable is evaluated at runtime. The approach you're using is attempting to evaluate the template at the time of task instantiation, resulting in an error. Instead, you should let Airflow handle the templating at runtime. So, define your Python function to accept the arguments, use op_kwargs to pass the templated arguments to your callable and check that your Python function handles the arguments correctly:
def foo(var):
    #(whathever you have in your function)
    print(var)

Then,
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

def execute_foo(**kwargs):
    var = kwargs['var']
    foo(var)

task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='mytask',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=execute_foo,
    op_kwargs={'var': "{{ var.json.mydict }}" },
    dag=dag
)

Hope this works.
